# CodedUI Selenium QTAgent32.exe Stale Element Reference Exception on control Exists

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests

In Visual Studio, C#, I have this test:

```
BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch(BaseURL + "/wizard");

var button = new HtmlButton(browser);
button.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlButton.PropertyNames.Id, "NewUser");

ClickButton(browser, "Login");

Playback.Wait(10000);

try {
    bool exists = button.Exists;
} catch {}
```

ClickButton initiates a javascript function which:

```
1. Hides all of the buttons.
2. initiates an ajax promise.
3. On Success, redirects to a dashboard page
4. On failure, un-hides the buttons.
```

As you'd imagine, 10 seconds after clicking the Login button, the "NewUser" button is certainly gone/stale since I am logged in.

If I debug, I can see that I get a StaleElementReferenceException.  If I run the tests, the browser explodes saying QTAgent32.exe has stopped working.

If I comment out the button.Exists line, I get no errors.

What I'm really attempting is a loop which checks for either the existence of the NewUser button, or the existence of a field on the Dashboard, so I know the result of the button click.

My problem is that the browser explodes when I run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Exists use `button.TryFind()` which will give you a boolean value and wont cause an exception.

Note: this my slow the process - to solve this:
reduce the  `Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout` before the search and return it to default value after search has finished:

```
    var def = Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout;
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = 1000;
    {
       Do workd
    }
    Playback.PlaybackSettings.SearchTimeout = def ;
```